# Laravel Nginx PHP-FPM specific url client_max_body_size

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I run my Laravel application on top of Nginx PHP-FPM.
I have a feature request that require the web page to allow video upload up to 100 MB.
What I don't want is to open the whole request to allow 100MB.

This is my initial nginx setup:

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /path-to-web/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name www.myweb.com;

    client_max_body_size 18m;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=www.myweb.com";
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path-to-cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path-to-cert/cert.key;

    root /path-to-web/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name www.myweb.com;

    client_max_body_size 18m;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=www.myweb.com";
    }
}
```

This is what I had tried so far with no luck (403 Request Entity too large):

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /path-to-web/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name www.myweb.com;

    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
    
    location / {
        client_max_body_size 18m;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }    

    location ~ ^/path-to-video-upload/.+\.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=\"www.myweb.com\"upload_max_filesize=\"256M\"post_max_size=\"256M\"";
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 18m;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=www.myweb.com";
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path-to-cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path-to-cert/cert.key;

    root /path-to-web/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name www.myweb.com;
    
    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 18m;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }    

    location ~ ^/path-to-video-upload/.+\.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=\"www.myweb.com\"upload_max_filesize=\"256M\"post_max_size=\"256M\"";
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 18m;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=www.myweb.com";
    }
}
```

Thank you for the helps.

Thanks to @Darryl E. Clarke answer, I manage to make it work.
SOLUTION:

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /path-to-laravel-app/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name www.myweb.com;

    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;

    client_body_buffer_size 16k;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 18M;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /path-to/upload-file/ {
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=\"www.myweb.com\"
            upload_max_filesize=\"256M\"
            post_max_size=\"256M\"";
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate /path-to-cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path-to-cert/cert.key;

    root /path-to-laravel-app/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name www.myweb.com;

    proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;

    client_body_buffer_size 16k;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 18M;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /path-to/upload-file/ {
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 256M;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=\"www.myweb.com\"
            upload_max_filesize=\"256M\"
            post_max_size=\"256M\"";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert to your original configuration and only change these:

```
 location / {
        client_max_body_size 18m;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }   

 location /path-to-video-upload {
        client_max_body_size 256m;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

You don't need to match any .php regex, unless your routes explicitly have php in them. It will match a full Laravel route and apply the body size limit to that URL only.

Comment: I'm still getting 413 Request Entity Too Large. I even test it without the custom location, and make the location / { client_max_body_size 256M; }

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I managed to find the solution (I have updated my question with the solution)